# Divergence of series by comparison test with inverse elements

Tags: sequences-and-series

The title is preliminary and should be changed if anyone has a better idea how to express this.

This is the series in question:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+4}{n^2-3n+1} := \sum a_n$$

What feels natural is a comparison to the harmonic series, since for any $n\geq3$:

$$\sum a_n \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$

But then the requirements for the series comparison test is not met, as $ \exists n\in \mathbb{N}: a_n\ngeq \frac{1}{n} $. The limit comparison as described here: [Khanacademy: Limit Comparison Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtbZZiSLemQ) also fails, since $ \exists n\in \mathbb{N}: a_n\lt 0 $.
I am somewhat inclined to just split the series up:
$$
\sum a_n=
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac{n+4}{n^2-3n+1}}_{\geq 0}
+
\sum_{n=10}^{\infty}{\frac{n+4}{n^2-3n+1}}\gt\sum_{n=10}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
=\infty
$$

But that obviously only shifts the problem over to the harmonic series still being divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely fine if there are some negative terms in the beginning of the sequence. The most important thing is that there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\geq n_0$. So you can use the limit comparison test with the harmonic series without any problems.

Comment: I honestly find that hard to believe, because there must be a tipping point of sorts where that is not true anymore, right? I guess somehow not, because the series diverges, but it still seems arbitrary. And any definition of the comparison test I came across so far requires that all elements be of the same sign.

Comment: I hope you agree that a finite number of terms doesn't have any effect on the convergence or divergence of the series. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. So if you can pick an $N$ such that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\geq N$ then you can use the limit comparison test for $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$. That will give you all the information about the original series.

Comment: Well yes, but obviously you change the value when doing that for a convergent sum. So you would just argue:  $\infty-x=\infty$ for all x?

Comment: Yes, for any finite number $x$ it is obviously true. The sum changes, but in your exercise you only need to know if the series converges or diverges. So it works.

Comment: Got it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The fast way uses *asymptotic equivalents*, which is valid since the general term of the series is ultimately positive (to be precise, for $n >2$):

$\;n+4\sim_\infty n$, $ \;n^2-3n+1\sim_\infty n^2$, so
$$\frac{n+4}{n^2-3n+1}\sim_\infty\frac n{n^2}=\frac1n, $$ 
which diverges.

Comment: That feels like violating limit theorems to me. Thanks, I will look that up! :)

Comment: There's a theorem asserting that two series  with positive, equivalent, terms both converge or both diverge. I don't see which theorem is violated?

Comment: No that wasn't the part I meant. But as I said, I will just have to read it up.